# Solar installer

Tags: roofing, solar

I'm considering purchasing my own solar panels and installing myself and doing all the paperwork. I want to do it myself for the experience. The problem is that my HOA won't allow me to do the work myself and also I'm worried about injuring myself on the roof. The solar companies won't deal with me, they want me to purchase the entire system from them. How do I find out if I can contract out the work to a freelance installer? Where would I ask?

Comment: Some places require a professional engineer to certify the plans. Some accept the electrical being done by homeowner, as long as it is inspected and actually matches the plans, but it is dangerous (more so than most home electrical), especially if long strings are used. Typically any electrician is qualified to perform the electrical part of the install, and in some states is qualified to perform everything, while others may require a general or constructor contractor oversee the panel mounting. Traditional solar installers have no interest in touching equipment already purchased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the region of the world you inhabit, your system may not be accepted in a grid-tie configuration. In Florida, USA, the local utility is required to examine and sign-off the installation. Additionally, local permitting may also require that the work be performed by licensed contractors.

Considering that you have to deal with an HOA, it's likely that you are not "far enough in the boonies" to get away with an off-grid solar array.

A licensed contractor has the skill set to locate correct attachment points in the roof structure (banging the hammer, listening to the thud) as well as to install the necessary wiring to interface with the panel and the electronics which will manage the power flow.

Most of the work is performed on the roof and if your concern is injuries associated with such a location, using professional contractors may be wise, as well as may be required by local codes.

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, I have to agree with Fred here. Roof top solar is not a DIY project. Lots of codes, rules, regs, esp. if grid tied (IE: Net metering), inspections, danger of working on a roof, etc. etc. etc.     This is one of the few times here when I say: "Call a pro". ....sorry.

Comment: You hate to agree with fred? That's a new one on me. (grin)

Comment: Sorry, Fred, poorly phrased.   I hated to say it because I knew it would lead me to "call a pro" advice, which I dislike doing here, so I reluctantly agreed with your answer. Nothing against you at all, I just hated having to agree....this isn't a DIY project. +  BTW, I did up vote your answer.